# Running a VBA code within Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working within Access 2013. I have two fields within a subform that I would like to lock if a button (yes/no field) is selected these two fields include Resume previous location and Personal Reference, the yes/no field is Resume Source Internal.

My code:

```
Private Sub Resume_Source_Internal_Click()
   If [Resume Source Internal].Value = True Then
      [Personal Reference].Enabled = True
      [Resume Previous Location].Enabled = False
   Else
      [Personal Reference].Enabled = True
      [Resume Previous Location].Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

The problem that I am having trouble with is that when I am selecting the button (yes/no) nothing is happening. I have ran this code before in another form and it worked perfectly. Is there anything that I could have missed? Personal Reference and Resume Previous Location are both look up fields.

Comment: Have you tried to compile step by step? stop the program at that sub and step forward.

Comment: I have not will try that now.

Comment: Agree w/@TedoG. - debugging step by step is _always_ the first thing to do when something's not working right.

Comment: I have figured it, I just code straight through my subform with setting up an event procedure for resume source internal.

Comment: If you have figured it out yourself, please close/delete this question as it doesn't really have a wide user-based need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Resume_Source_Internal_Click()
   If [Resume Source Internal].Value = True Then
      [Personal Reference].Enabled = True
      [Resume Previous Location].Enabled = False
   Else
      [Personal Reference].Enabled = False
      [Resume Previous Location].Enabled = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Note that in the `Else`, I switched the values of `False` and `True`. As you have it written, you're setting the exact same values on both sides of the `If...Else`

Answer (score 0):

Would this code work for you - set the fields to one enabled and one disabled in the Property Sheet.

When you click the button the enabled property will switch from True to False and vice-versa.

```
Private Sub Resume_Source_Internal_Click()

    Me.Personal_Reference.Enabled = Not Me.Personal_Reference.Enabled
    Me.Resume_Previous_Location.Enabled = Not Me.Resume_Previous_Location.Enabled

End Sub
```